# Regex Pattern Matching Concatenation

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate the results of Regex Pattern Matching using only Regex syntax?

The specific instance is a program is allowing regex syntax to pull info from a file, but I would like it to pull from several portions and concatenate the results.

For instance:

Input string: 1234567890

Desired result string: 2389

Regex Pattern match: (?<=1).+(?=4)***%%***(?<=7).+(?=0)

Where ***%%*** represents some form of concatenation syntax.  Using starting and ending with syntax is important since I know the field names but not the values of the field.

Does a keyword that functions like ***%%*** exist?  Is there a more clever way to do this?  Must the code be changed to allow multiple regex inputs, automatically concatenating?

Again, the pieces to be concatenated may be far apart with unknown characters in between.  All that is known is the information surrounding the substrings.

2011-08-08 edit: The program is written in C#, but changing the code is a major undertaking compared to finding a regex-based solution.

Comment: Normally nope, but some programming languages have an extended version of regex functionality. For example in PHP you can use **e** modifier when replacing strings.

Comment: The program parsing the regex is written in c# on .net 3.5 i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you want to match and what language you're using, it's impossible to give you an exact answer.  However, the usual way to approach something like this is to use [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

In C#:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=1)(.+)(?=4).+(?<=7)(.+)(?=0)";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

string result = m.Groups[0] + m.Groups[1];
```

The same approach can be applied to many other languages as well.

**Edit**

If you are not able to change the code, then there's no way to accomplish what you want.  The reason is that in C#, the regex string itself doesn't have any power over the output.  To change the result, you'd have to either change the called method of the Regex class or do some additional work afterwards.  As it is, the method called most likely just returns either a `Match` object or a list of matching objects, neither of which will do what you want, regardless of the input regex string.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand the problem is trivial in C#, but the logistics of changing the application are difficult.  The question is if a solution exists with regex alone, since that would be much easier to change.  Thanks again.

edit: We were typing at the same time must be.  I agree it seems there is no way to do concatenation without modifying the code.

Comment: Responding to the fundamental question: "Is it possible to concatenate the results of Regex Pattern Matching using only Regex syntax?". I think it's important to remember that Regex isn't a programming *language* so much as a programming *tool*. Thus, there's no *one* way to use it, because it's just a tool that's used differently by many languages. To do something "using only Regex syntax" is a challenging way to approach the problem.

Comment: I see the err of my thinking.  I am fairly new to regex and assumed it was standard across all implementations.

Comment: The syntax of Regular Expressions is more or less standard, meaning that `[a-z]` will, in all the languages that I know, match any single lowercase letter.  What varies is how that syntax is used to get different results, such as finding matches, replacing text, filtering, etc.