# .NET Regex to back capture only the number from a matching group

Tags: .net, regex

I need to configure an app that takes a regex as a parameter. It is a .NET application, and uses the default .NET regex engine.

In the app, there is a string that looks either like this:

```
blah blah blah 123-123PQ
```

or this:

```
blah blah blah 456456ZR
```

I need the 123123 or the 465456 without the rest of the string, in a single named capture group

I have gotten this far:

```
(\b(?<number>\d+(?:-\d*)?)PQ|(?<number>\d+(?:\d*)?)ZR\b)
```

This captures either the first set of numbers or the second, but in the first format the result still has the "-" character in it.

My question:
How do I do a backreference and grab only the numeric portion from the  capture group?

Comment: Do you have the ability to change what the app does with the matched text? You could parse each part into two named capture groups and then concatenate them together.

Comment: @antiduh - I can change the app, but it is running at a customer site with a bug and I would like to have configured the bug away. No worries, I'll just release a new version of the app :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible - here's a question that seems to be exactly the same thing you're asking for:

[Regex Pattern Matching Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981950/regex-pattern-matching-concatenation)

Comment: Thanks, I've come to the same conclusion :-)